# SQL Error [42501]: The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation

Tags: sql, db2, websphere, dbeaver

'''Hi

I try to connect to IBM DATABASE using DBrieaver . But, when i try to see the data in tables. I am getting the following errors.
SQL Error [42501]: The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.

[image]

'''

Comment: What user ID do you use to connect? What user ID did you use when you created the table?

Comment: DB2 Command Line processor is not asking me any user-id when i am creating a Database. I created a database directly using the command Line and connect to sample then i started moving from one .ixf files to ibm database by teminate and db2move commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply means that you are trying to execute a statement that you don't have the privileges for.

For example, you might be trying to `SELECT * FROM foo;`, but `foo` is a view or a table created by another user, who did not bother to grant SELECT on foo to your user.

Unless the owner of the table - or an administrator - grants you SELECT on table foo, you will remain stuck.